# Trouble making SearchView widget working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, searchview

I'm actually trying to perform a search from a fragment. I would just like to display the text (with a Toast) the user is trying to search with the SearchView widget which in inflated to the fragment. According to the Android documentation, when a user performs a search with the SearchView widget, the application should start a SearchableActivity. The problem is that I can't make it start a SearchableActivity.

Here is my Android Manifest :

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ClientActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_client"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
```

Here is the fragment called in ClientActivity :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_organisation_search, container, false);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view_id);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();
        return view;
    }
```

The layout it inflates :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view_id"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/block">         

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView> 
</ScrollView>
```

The SearchableActivity.java :

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }

    }       
    public void doMySearch(String query) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), query+"wsh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("The query : ",query);

    }
}
```

Here is searchable.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

It's been days I'm trying to make the searchview widget working. If you have any idea I would be thankful.

**EDIT** 
I made it work adding this code to my fragment :

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Create a Searchable Configuration - Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableConfiguration

Comment: I did, as you can see in my AndroidManifest : `<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>`, I created an xml file for a searchable config

Comment: Using the search widget allows you to put the search box anywhere in your activity. Instead of putting it in your activity layout, you should usually use SearchView as an action view in the app bar.

Comment: I really need to put the search box in a specific place instead of the app bar. I resolved my problem anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add searchable.xml

This file is traditionally named **searchable.xml** and must be saved in the res/xml/ project directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: I did it already, check my android manifest: `<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>` . Just edited my post to show you the content of my searchable.xml file.